# Buildroot devicetree overlay for MCP2515

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, kernel-module, buildroot, can-bus

I have connected an MCP2515 to the Raspberry Compute-Module and now it would be nice if I could make it work.

We use a distribution based on buildroot - but unfortunately we can't manage to load the devicetree-overlay for the MCP2515.

We activated device-tree in the linux-menuconfig plus we created overlay folder in /boot plus we activated dtoverlay in /boot/config.txt

What else should we take care of, to make CAN work on our system?

Thank you.